# testing :reject_if in anaf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :languages, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :languages,   :reject_if => lambda { |l| l[:name].blank? }
end
```

I want to test reject_if part with RSpec 2.0.0. Currently I have two simple test cases for that

```
  it "should not save language without name by accepts_nested_attributes" do
    lambda {
      @user.update_attributes!("languages_attributes"=>{"0"=>{}})
    }.should_not change(Language, :count)
  end

  it "should save language with name by accepts_nested_attributes" do
    lambda {
      @user.update_attributes!("languages_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"lang_name"}})
    }.should change(Language, :count).by(1)
  end
```

However I'm quite new to testing and it looks really weird imho. 
I wonder if this is a right way to test reject_if? And is there is a nicer way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see that you're looking to test the `reject_if` then the best way to do this is to test it directly:

```
anaf_for_languages = User.nested_attributes_options[:languages]
anaf_for_languages[:reject_if].call({ "name" => "" }).should be_true
```

If it's `true`, then `name` is blank. I think this is a little more succinct than your code, but not as immediately obvious.

Comment: Your approach is clear and I have upvoted it. Your example does not depend on the view and form and it sounds good => more isolation. However I am not sure if it is a right way to do, since my intention is to check if language record is not saved when a user submits a form with language name field blank. Maybe this is another question, but what is a good strategy to follow when unit-testing - isolate from everything as much as possible or try to simulate a real application workflow? if the answer is latter option, does my example is valid and correct?

Comment: @Tadas: There was nothing about a view or a form in the original question so I answered to the best of my ability in that respect. If you're looking to test the view / form on this then I would recommend going with something such as Cucumber or Steak for full-stack integration testing.